# What would be the regex to fine the bold numbers

Tags: regex

I tried `\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{0,3}` but it misses 34.89 and 23.89

I want all the number sequences in the text below except 28.72%

```
34.89
0105.93.10  ghghghh
0105.93.20  ghghhh 
jjjjjhjj 0105.93.30 jsdfsd iksifsdjfk sdfsdk
0105.93.40ierfgg dfgkdfg dfgolgh 23.89
28.72%
```

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Why don't you want to find `28.72%`?

Comment: Tell us the rules in English that you want to implement as a regex.

Comment: I want to find all number sequence in the form xxx.xx.xx or xxxx.xx.xxxx or xxx.xx or xxxx.xxx.xxx where x in a number digit

Comment: `xxxx.xx.xxxx` has four digits in its last number sequence, your regex only allows three. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex requires two dots to be present. You need to make the last dot-digit sequence optional, and you need to exclude matches where `%` or another digit follows (otherwise `28.7` within `28.72%` would match):

```
\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?(?![0-9%])
```

Comment: This almost did it but it goes and find the pattern in the substring example 0105.93.10 yields 0105.93.10  and 93.10, I would only like 0105.93.10

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but in his example it does not match the `.40` at the end because it is immediately followed by "i," not word boundary

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Ah yes, thanks for noticing. Will fix this immediately.

Comment: how can I find only 0105.93.10 and not 0105.93.10 and 93.10

Comment: @Paulute: It shouldn't be finding both because regexes in general don't find overlapping matches. What exactly are you doing that causes both matches to be found?

Answer (score 1):

Make the last part optional

```
\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?
```

Your original expression was requiring the period.

You were not very specific with your rules about matching `%`, so I made this:

```
\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?(?=[^%\d]|$)
```

The last part is a positive lookahead for any non-%  non-digit character or the end of the line.  It needs to be non-digit as well or else `28.7` will match the rest of the expression, and the last `2` matches a non-percent character.

Comment: This almost did it but it; find the pattern in the substring example 0105.93.10 yields 0105.93.10 and 93.10, I would only like 0105.93.10

Comment: There should be no sub-expression because the `?:` should prevent capturing

Answer (score 0):

This will find all groups of numbers, separated by single dots, that are not followed by `%`:

```
(?:\d+\.)+\d+(?!\%)
```

It requires at least one digit on each side of a dot.  Other than that, it doesn't care how many digits are in each group.  At requires there be at least one dot in the number.

This would also require each group to have between 2 and 4 digits:

```
(?:\d{2,4}\.)+\d{2,4}(?!\%)
```

Comment: I don't want it to look in to substring of the find just move to the next find ex. 0105.93.10 not 0105.93.10,105.93.10, 05.93.10 etc

Comment: @Paulute, it won't do that; it will only give you the complete matches.

Comment: @Paulute, if that is the result you are getting, maybe you are using the regex incorrectly in your program.  What language is this?